# Jenkins error: Plugin requires Maven version 2.2.1

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a solution in IntelliJ that builds fine on my local.

Extract from the POM:

```
 <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.20</version>
            <dependencies>

            </dependencies>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

I have installed Jenkins on my local and created a simple Maven project and pointed it to my POM file from within Jenkins.

When I build the solution from Jenkins I get the following error:

[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error resolving version for 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin': Plugin requires Maven version 2.2.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch

On Jenkins I have installed:
Maven Integration plugin
2.15.1

Any ideas / advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My own silly mistake.  Had to specify the Maven and Java JDK under:
Manage Jenkins --> Global Tool Configuration

After this everything worked.